# Restrict sybase command stop_iq to certain linux users

Tags: linux, sybase

I want to restrict access to stop_iq database shutdown utility to authorized users only under Linux, for example to the user 'dev' that belongs to group 'grp_dev'. I know the command is under this path:

`/sybaseiq/IQ-15_4/bin64/stop_iq`

And it could be also the same for start command:

`/sybaseiq/IQ-15_4/bin64/start_iq`

Answer (score 1):

If the file has no special setuid flags  (i.e. `ls -l stop_iq` shows only a mix of the chars "rwx-" in the first field) you can simply, as root, `chown dev stop_iq` and `chmod u=rx,og= stop_iq` so only user dev can execute the file. This assumes no one else but you can `sudo` to root.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to user "dev" can not execute the file? what would be the instruction?

Comment: @MSS for example, if you `sudo chown root stop_iq` and do the `chmod` also as above, then only root can run the program. Choose any user, like root, that is not "dev".

Comment: I need that `root` and `sybase` users can run the command `stop_iq`. The user `dev` and other users cannot perform that command. What would be the sequence of command I have to write?. Sorry, but I'm not an experienced linux user.

Comment: @MSS root can always read files, so to let sybase and root run a file, `chown sybase stop_iq` and `chmod u=rx,og= stop_iq`, then dev and others should not be able to read nor execute the file.